# Highcharts: How to create Pie-Donut Chart with 1 slice to have 1 layer and other slices to have 2 layers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to create a pie chart similar to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut but one slice will not have 2 layers. Imagine MSIE doesnt have subcategories and will display as 1 layer. I'll be using it when a category's (eg MSIE) sub-categories' values are 0. How do create a pie chart that has a combination of 1 layer slice and other slices to have 2 layers?

If I set the MSIE subcategory to zero, the 2nd layer of other categories occupy MSIE, in which I want it to be occupied by MSIE by being 1 layer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not avaiable, because we use two separated series, which use differenet size (innerSize parameter).